# Service Does Not Launch Console Application

Tags: vb.net, windows, service, cmd

TLDR: My console application runs if I click on it manually however it does not run when called by service while using StartProcess or Shell.

Could this be a permission issue?

Details:
I've written a small windows service application that checks a remote location folder for a product key and updates the local machine if the product key is different than what is entered. I thought this would be a simple project for my first foray into windows services.

The service runs using a timer every hour (for testing the interval is every 30 seconds). Originally the service would perform the updating but I ran into a more complicated issue accessing the UNC path (I would have to use Impersonation Classes).

So while testing the code in a console version of the application, I noticed it was able to access the network location without supplying credentials. So I rewrote the service so it calls the console application instead. But no matter how I write it I can't get the console application to launch from the service.

If anymore information is needed please feel free to ask!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A service is not designed to interact with a user so is deliberately isolated from users desktops. Use process manager to see if its spawning the process - don't expect it to pop-up on your desktop.

Comment: It works from the console application because it's running as *you*. It fails from the service because the service doesn't have the necessary permissions. If the service runs the console application, then the console application will be running as the service and *still* not have the necessary permissions. Run the service under an account with the right permissions or get the permissions changed on the UNC path and the code should work fine from within the service.

Answer (score 0):

Damien hit the nail on the head, the issue is that when you run the console app, you are running it as you, which has access to the UNC. When the service runs your console app, it is running it as the user you tied to the service. You have a couple options:

- 1: Setup the service to run as a user with access to the UNC
- 2: Use Impersonation to connect as the user you want to.

Either way, running it from a console application instead of your service is useless.

I have included a class I created that makes impersonation easy:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

''' <summary>
''' Used to temporarily impersonate another user
''' Must use a USING block or dispose of instance to undo impersonation
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class ImpersonateFNS
    Implements IDisposable

    Declare Function LogonUserA Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
                                                ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private _impersonatedUser As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing
    Private _loggedOn As Boolean = False

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Should call this in a USING block OR, make sure you dispose this object when done impersonating
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String)
        Dim token As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        'If (LogonUserA(UserName, Domain, Password, 2, 0, token) <> 0) Then
        If (LogonUserA(UserName, Domain, Password, 9, 0, token) <> 0) Then
            _loggedOn = True
            Dim newIdentity As WindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(token)
            _impersonatedUser = newIdentity.Impersonate()
        Else
            Dim ret As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
            'Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret)
            'Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(String.Format("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret))
            Throw New Security.SecurityException(String.Format("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly Property LoggedOn As Boolean
        Get
            Return _loggedOn
        End Get
    End Property


#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            End If
            If _impersonatedUser IsNot Nothing Then
                _impersonatedUser.Undo()
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Create the class as shown above and then call is in a USING block so it will undo the impersonation when you are done doing your business. like so:

```
Using x as New ImpersonationFNF("MyDomain", "User","Password")
    'Copy, read, whatever the stuff you need to do here
End Using
```